# JSONRPC usage in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, json-rpc

I'm quite a beginner with Ruby On Rails and I need to implement client part of JSON API in order to use some external service.

I found a gem called **jsonrpc** and it looks perfect for me.
I've added it to my Gemfile as:

```
gem 'jsonrpc'
gem 'json'
```

and ran `bundle`

My code looks like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

def index
    d = JsonRpcClient.new 'http://remote.bronni.ru/Dictionaries.ashx'
    @countries = d.getCountries
end
```

But when I try to access it as `http://localhost:3000/search`, Rails says:

```
NameError in SearchesController#index
uninitialized constant SearchController::JsonRpcClient
```

I only have little experience with Rails so I'm asking you guys to help me out.
I really need to get this to work ASAP.

Thank you all in advance! I really appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**

I've tryed to get ActiveResource to work but I can't get how it build URL's. The remote service is not a Ruby XML app. (**http://remote.bronni.ru/Dictionaries.ashx**) And I need to use **getCountries** method so the URL should be **http://remote.bronni.ru/Dictionaries.ashx/getCountries**

Comment: ActiveResoyrce has builtin support for json rest api

Comment: Hm, thanks. But I thought it emulates ActiveModel and I'm not sure how to use it. =(

Comment: Queries are written the same way which is brilliant. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: I mean this remote module has many methods like _getCountries, getCurrencies_ and so on... I've created a model like 

`class Dictionaries < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://remote.bronni.ru/Dictionaries.ashx"
  self.format = :json
end`

But how do I access a particular method?

Comment: Another problem with ARes is I can't get how it builds URLs. When I call **@countries = Dictionaries.get('getCountries')** I'm expecting it to be **http://remote.bronni.ru/Dictionaries.ashx/getCountries** as I have **self.site = "http://remote.bronni.ru/Dictionaries.ashx/"** in my dictionaries.rb. When I try to perform this thing it echoes _iderrornameJSONRPCErrormessageMethod not found._

Comment: instead of `JsonRpcClient.new` try `JsonRPC::Client.new`

Comment: Don't use this gem. Documentation is NIL.